# Replace an object in the list or leave the same one using Stream.map()

Tags: java, loops, foreach, java-stream

There is a list of elements. Task: if a record is found in the database by the name of the field of an element from the list, create a new object from the found record and insert it instead of the existing element. If not, leave the element in the list (do nothing).

Sample code:

```
result = list.stream().map(element -> {
    Optional<Object> dbRecord = repository.findByName(element.getName());

    dbRecord.ifPresent(
            x -> {
                x.setSmth(element.getSmth());
                x.setSmth1(element.getSmth1());
                ...
            }
    );

    return dbRecord.orElse(element);

}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I've checked in the debugger - at any steps method repository.findByName() returns Optional.enpty(). The second call to `return` with the returning of `element`, I catch an error:

```
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 2; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:385) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy186.findByName(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at ru.app.MyService.lambda$processRequest$4(MyService.java:166) ~[my-application-2.0.0.jar:?]
```

I understand how to solve the problem with a general loop, but I would like to understand how the stream.map() method works. Tell me please, what is my mistake?

Comment: `query did not return a unique result: 2`. It's your database things that don't work, not the stream.

Comment: Data returned from the database has more than one value where it should have been only one. That seems to be the issue. The same code would not work for normal for loops too.

Comment: Thx u all, it was my first assumption too, but Optional.empty() in debugger made me confused. I've checked the same query with type List returned and there are really 2 results found.